# Remote debugging with eclipse indigo without executable

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-indigo

I am using eclipse indigo on windows as an IDE to develop an application for an embedded linux environment.  The toolchain is on the linux environment, an I do not have a native version for windows.  I would like to use putty to connect to GDB running on the remote target.  I have this method already working for remote builds.

When trying to debug eclipse asks for an executable.  It will not accept a blank line or a random executable, returning the error "Program is not a recognized executable." Is there a method or debugging setup that I can use GDB/Eclipse in this manner without the executable?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using windows, but you might have path munging problems when debugging using this method that is, eclipse simply executes the gdb you tell it too. Then it passes path information to that gdb session to start the process

you can turn on gdb console output and see what the values being passed to gdb look like

good source of info

http://wiki.eclipse.org/TM_and_RSE_FAQ#How_can_I_do_Remote_Debugging_with_CDT.3F

using Preferences->C/C++->Debug->Common Source Lookup

you might be able to set up a path converter

This guy uses a xcompiler but has some good info about setting up on windows

http://www.appinf.com/download/EclipseEmbeddedLinuxPaper.pdf